# Trying avoid add same fragment twice to backStack, popBackStackImmediate always return false

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, back-stack

I'm trying avoid adding the same fragment to backStack with this method:

```
public static void replaceFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Fragment fragment, Boolean addToBackStack) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

        if (addToBackStack && !fragmentPopped && fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) {
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
//                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .addToBackStack(backStateName) // was 'backStateName'
                    .commit();
        } else {
            if (!addToBackStack)
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
//                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .disallowAddToBackStack()
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

Navigation Drawer contains: ImageView with `profilePhoto` which opens `ProfileMainFragment` and few categories which opens `MainFragmentCategory`. `Boolean addToBackStack` is `false` when fragment is choosen from `navigationDrawerMenu` and `true` when is choosen within fragment (move from `MainFragmentCategory` to `DetialFragmentCategory`) or click `profilePhoto` in `navigationDrawer`.

`fragmentPopped` is always `false`, why is that so? Even if I click `profilePhoto` and again `profilePhoto` in `navigationDrawer`. It should avoid to add it to backStack for a second (and third, and fourth...) time, but it didn't.

Any idea how can I make it right?

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to accomplish to prevent adding same fragment twice to backStack? BackStack is like navigation histroy. If user go from A > B > A > C, the user press back in C. He should go back to A instead of B.

Comment: I want to avoid something like this: A > B > B > B and make it looks like this: A > B.

Comment: How about when the user click on the drawer, you check the current fragement. If it is the same, then do not replace it.

Comment: ok, how can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the following code before you replace your fragment.

```
// Replace fragmentCotainer with your container id
Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentCotainer);
// Return if the class are the same
if(currentFragment.getClass().equals(fragment.getClass())) return;
```