# How to avoid replacing same fragment over and over?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am creating my first android application. After doing required homework I bring here for help.

Fragment A can be invoked from Navigation Drawer. Again if i slide Navigation Bar and invoke Fragment A. its overlapping perviously Invoked Fragment A. Problem is User have to click back twice to get to home screen.

I sharing few screenshot and snippet.

Launching Fragment A(Help_Fragment())

```
 private void createHelp() {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Log.d(taglaunch, "Switching to Help Fragment");
    Fragment fragment = new Help_Fragment();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left,
            R.animator.slide_out_right, R.animator.exit_to_left, R.animator.exit_to_right);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.app_bar, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

}
```

Oncreate

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(taglaunch, "on Create - AppDrawer");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_appdrawer);
    mainActivityAdapter = new MainActivityAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    navigate();
    switchtofragment();
    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(backStackListener);

}

 public void switchtofragment() {
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB2"));
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mainActivityAdapter);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

public void navigate() {

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

[Fragment A screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h78b3.jpg)

[Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJcjy.jpg)

Comment: there are several ways to check which is current fragment (displayed) you can do this check in `createHelp()` or other methods that "replace" fragment, and if current displayed fragment is same type as the one being displayed, just `return;`

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38475373/3436343

Comment: @Yazan thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

> If fragment exists, You can replace the fragment using the below code.

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead check if the Help_Fragment already exists by using findFragmentByTag() method of Fragment Manager. If it does not exist, then you can proceed to create one. Apart from that, replace method replaces fragment that was added programatically i.e. to a container like a frame layout. But this solution can be just a work around. Try this out and let us know. :)

Code :-

```
FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    Help_Fragment fragment1= (Help_Fragment) manager.findFragmentByTag("Help_Fragment");
    if(fragment1==null)
    {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Log.d(taglaunch, "Switching to Help Fragment");
        Fragment fragment = new Help_Fragment();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left,
                R.animator.slide_out_right, R.animator.exit_to_left, R.animator.exit_to_right);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.app_bar, fragment,"Help_Fragment").addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
    else{
        // Display a Toast that fragment exists
    }
```